# How to write test script for grid checkbox in webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

A checkbox in Selenium web driver. How to automate a checkbox in the grid. I am not able to assign IDs into the cells/row- checker checkbox

Answer (score 0):

We cannot help without seeing the code of your page. Just be aware that there are other [Locator Strategies](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/#locator-strategies) like [CSS Selectors](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) or [XPath Selectors](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727) which are capable of uniquely identifying any element in the [DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model) even if it doesn't have a unique [ID attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

If you're using [Java client bindings](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/) and the "grid" is a normal [HTML Table](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) - you will find [Table](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements/blob/master/htmlelements-java/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/htmlelements/element/Table.java) class from the [HtmlElements framework](https://github.com/yandex-qatools/htmlelements) very useful.